# Sending requests to multiple different APIs in a single batch

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, google-sheets-api

I received an email state that my Google Cloud Project used Global HTTP Batch serving endpoints which are scheduled to be turned down on March 25, 2019.

After some study, I found something that may be relevant [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1178), 

*"What's being discontinued is sending requests to multiple different APIs in a single batch...*"

So I suspect it is because of my code here in the Google Cloud Project :

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
print_r($client);

//create new spreadsheet
$sheetService = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
$requestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_Spreadsheet([
                  'properties' => [
                      'title' => $new_sheet_title
                  ]
               ]);
$response = $sheetService->spreadsheets->create($requestBody);
$spreadsheetId = $response->spreadsheetId;

$driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$client->setUseBatch(true);
$batch = $driveService->createBatch();

$userPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
                      'type' => 'user',
                      'role' => 'writer',
                      'emailAddress' => 'mypersonalemail@gmail.com'
                  ));
$request = $driveService->permissions->create(
              $spreadsheetId, $userPermission, array('fields' => 'id'));
$batch->add($request, 'user'); 
$results = $batch->execute();  
$client->setUseBatch(false); 

//then no longer using Drive API, only using Sheet API to do formatting...
```

When I print_r() my $client, I saw this :

```
[requestedScopes:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
        [1] => https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
    )
```

I'm using *Google Sheet API* to create spreadsheet and using *Drive API* to allow permission to my personal email (Well, why am I used this way is another story...)
By the way, I'm using *Google Client Library (v2.2.1) php beta*

So I guess what I have to do is

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

//using setScopes to overwrite original scopes
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);
$sheetService = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
//create my spreadsheet

$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
//allow permission to my personal email

//then set it back & do formatting to my spreadsheet
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);
$sheetService = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

...
```

I tested and for sure it works

**So my question is :**

1. Which part of my code are sending batch request to both Sheet and Driver API? As I check my batch update request, no request that call to both API are found. (refer to [here](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html))

2. I'm not sure whether my new script solve the problem. As service not yet turn down by Google, so I'm not sure my new script will continue to work after March 25, 2019

I hope I state my concern clearly. Feel free to ask for more details.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be sending a batch request to the Google drive api.

```
$client->setUseBatch(true);
$batch = $driveService->createBatch();

$userPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
                      'type' => 'user',
                      'role' => 'writer',
                      'emailAddress' => 'mypersonalemail@gmail.com'
                  ));
$request = $driveService->permissions->create(
              $spreadsheetId, $userPermission, array('fields' => 'id'));
$batch->add($request, 'user'); 
$results = $batch->execute();  
$client->setUseBatch(false);
```

All of your requests in this batch request appear to be going to google Drive api.  I dont see any signs that you are mixing apis in this at all.   You will not be effected by  the change.

Comment: That's what I think too. As Google send email saying that my project are using Global HTTP Batch Endpoint that going to turn down next year. From what I know, my project not using any of that but Google API Client Library to call Google API. 

So I have nothing to worry about right?

Comment: I ran though and checked a lot of the client libraries when this first came out.  Most of them had already changed their code.   Others where in the process.   You should be good